# Cannot send form data to Firebase using Next.js

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am currently learning how to use Next.js to build a simple website with a submission form. However, I have not been able to write to Firebase database. I have previously successfully in doing so using React.js.

This is the index.js file I put under service folder:

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENTID,
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

And the following code is for the form and page:

```
"use client"

import React, {useState} from "react";
import "@styles/booking.css";
import {collection, addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "@service/index";

//localhost:3000/booking

function Booking() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [dropdownSelect, setDropdownSelect] = useState ("");
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  
  function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const Bookings = collection(db, "bookings");
    addDoc(Bookings, {
      formName: username,
      formNumber: number,
      formEmail: email,
      formDrop: dropdownSelect,
      formText: userText,
    }).then(response => {console.log(response)}).catch(error => {console.log(error.message)})    
  }


  return (
    <div className="bookingContainer">
      <h1>Book your service today</h1>

      <form className="bookingForm" method="POST" onSubmit={handleForm}>
        
        <div className="formField">
          <label>Name: </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" defaultValue={username}
          onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>

        <div className="formField">
          <label>Number: </label>
          <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Number" value={number}
          onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>

        <div className="formField">
          <label>email: </label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value={email}
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>

        <div className="serviceDropDown">
          <label>Choose a service: </label>
          <select name="serviceSelection" id="serviceSelection" value={dropdownSelect} onChange={e => setDropdownSelect(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="Menu A">The Caress</option>
            <option value="Menu B">The Meticulous</option>
            <option value="Menu C">The Overhaul</option>
            <option disabled={true} defaultValue={true}>--------------</option>
            <option value="wheelbuild">Wheel Building</option>
            <option value="frameprotect">Frame Protection</option>
            <option value="pedals">Pedals Service</option>
            <option value="other">Other (Please specify)</option>
          </select> 
        </div>

        <textarea className="serviceText" name="userText" id="userText" placeholder="Please enter your request here." defaultValue={userText}
        onChange={e => setUserText(e.target.value)}></textarea>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

      </form>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Booking;
```

So based on my past experience with React, a similar form is able to write to Firebase. However, it does not seem to work in this case, nor does it post any error in the console or network section of Chrom's developer tool.

I do understand that I am not handling any errors at the moment. However, I was expecting it to at least write to Firebase.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you import 'db' from '@utils/formsubmission' ?

Comment: Provided `@utils/formsubmission` is the same as _"the index.js file I put under Service folder"_, I don't see any problem here. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler my bad, it is meant to be db from service/index.

Comment: @Philisonstrike your assumption is correct. I am only assuming it is not working as the data is not reflected on firestore. Previously, when i was using React, despite testing locally, it was able to write the data to the database.